# Tablas corruptas en Mysql con Engine InnoDB - Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

Estoy realizando la restauracion de una BD corrupta, es decir, no puedo realizar consultas,modifaciones, actualizaciones etc. Marca el error siguiente:

`Error 1146 (42S502): Table 'nombre_tabla' doesn't exist`.

Debido a este error no puedo realizar procesos de recuperacion como `opimize table "nombre_tabla"`, `alter table "nombre_tabla" engine=innodb`(Son los que he tratado de implementar y unos de los que mas veo en la web).

Sabiendo esto, decidi implementar el metodo de `innodb_force_recovery = n`, donde n es un numero del 1 al 6. Esta linea se coloca en un archivo de configuracion de mysql que se encuentra en la carpeta etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf .
Una vez anadiendo esta linea puedo implementar el comando `mysqlcheck --check "database" --user=root --password="contrasena"`. 
Este comando permite visualizar si las tablas tienen alguna falla o si estan corruptas.

Aqui es donde comienza lo interesante, ya que en esta parte puedo visualiziar las tablas que se encuentran corrompidas. Todas ellas me marcan el siguiente error:

`InnoDB: The B-tree of index "PRIMARY" is corrupted
error: Corrupt`.

Como puedo resolver mi error? Espero y haber explicado correctamente el problema,  muchas gracias :)

Comment: **Probaste haciendo esto?:** 1) Exportando la tabla. 2) Una vez exportada, luego borrar la misma de la DB. 3) Crear una nueva con el mismo nombre que la que borraste recién, y a su vez el archivo que exportaste anteriormente debería tener el mismo nombre con extensión sql. 4) Andá a la tabla "vacía" recién creada y luego a importar, seleccioná el archivo e importala. 5) En el caso te que no tengas más la columna numérica primaria lo vemos que quizás se puede hacer un par de intentos para anexar una nueva u otra cosa. Ojalá te salga bien.

Comment: Hola, si, ya lo intente. Me marca `Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table "tabla" at row: "x"`

Comment: Por lo que te dice el msj es que no te lo deja borrar. Bueno todo bien, pero te la deja exportar?, por que de última la exportas,  y la creas en otra Db nueva con el mismo nombre etc...

Comment: No, no me deja exportarla tampoco... Es un problema bastante latoso..